# MySQL alias error with natural join;

Tags: mysql

```
select name
     , course_id 
  from 
     ( select * 
         from takes 
        where 'year' >= 2008
     ) 
natural 
  join student;
```

it gives me "EVERY DERIVED TABLE MUST HAVE ITS OWN ALIAS".

what is wrong with it. I cant find it pls help!

Comment: Why do you have a subquery at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add one alias to subquery:

```
select t.name, t.course_id from (select * from takes where year>=2008) as t natural join student;
```

Comment: and also what should be its equivalent query in the language of Relational Algebra? any idea?

Comment: i've basic knowledge of R.A. Let me try

Comment: This should be the R.A. : π name, course_id (ρt ((year >= 2008)(takes)) ⨝ (student))

Comment: If the above answer solved your problem then kindly accept it as answer and upvote it. That'll be really helpful to future visitors. Thank you.